# How can I populate a NameValueCollection via a parameter in a shared method?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, query-string, argument-passing, namevaluecollection

I have a code segment:

```
var requestMock = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
var queryString = new NameValueCollection();
queryString["abc"] = "123";
queryString["qwe"] = "456";
queryString["yui"] = "678";
...
requestMock.SetupGet(rqst => rqst.QueryString).Returns(queryString);
```

Now, I would like to have the above segment written as a method:

```
var requestMock = GetRequestMock(???);
```

I intend to send the query string key/values which can be anything. 
And the count of k/v pairs also can be anything.

```
public Mock<HttpRequestBase> GetRequestMock(???)
{
var requestMock = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
....
requestMock.SetupGet(rqst => rqst.QueryString).Returns(queryString);
return requestMock;
}
```

What would be the best way to do this eficiently and simply?

Comment: What happens currently when you are running the code in the `Mock<HttpRequestBase>GetRequestMock(){}` Nethod

Comment: @DJKRAZE There is no such method now.

Comment: what do you mean there is no such method you have it written in your question..I am confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use a `Dictionary`:

```
public Mock<HttpRequestBase> GetRequestMock(Dictionary<string, object> queryParms)
{
    var queryString = new NameValueCollection();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in queryParms)
    {
        queryString[kvp.Key] = Convert.ToString(kvp.Value);
    }

    ...
}
```

and then you can call it like this:

```
GetRequestMock(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "abc", "123" }, { "qwe", "456" } } );
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. SHould it be KeyValuePair<string, object> ?

Comment: @GilliVilla, yes, I didn't have a compiler in front of me. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Got an error "cannot convert source type object to destination type string.

Comment: any reason for Dictionary<string,object> instead of Dictionary<string,string> ?